# How to smoothly slide the page up when I slide a part of it out?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am currently working on a page where there is a form, and once the form is submitted, it slowly slides up and gets removed from the HTML. Now the other part of the page that is on the bottom of the form just kinda jumps up, but I would like it to smoothly slide up so it covers the area where the form previously was. How is that possible? I am using HTML, CSS, Javascript and jQuery

Comment: Please post your current HTML, CSS, and JS

Comment: What have you done so far?